# Разбить текст по пунктам

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть на входе строка типа такой:

```
1. qqqq
qqqq
qq
qqqqq

2. www
wwww
www
ww

3. eeee
eeee
eeee
```

Мне нужно по итогу получить массив строк

```
"qqqq
qqqq
qq
qqqqq"

"www
wwww
www
ww"

"eeee
eeee
eeee"
```

Как это сделать лучше всего? Пытался изобрести подобную регулярку, но не особо успешно, не знаю как цеплять последний пункт `[0-9]+\.(?<text>[\s\S]+?)(?=^[0-9]+\.)`

Comment: Попробуйте в группе позитивного просмотра вперед добавить логическое ИЛИ, указав завершение текста `\Z`: `(?=^[0-9]+\.|\Z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я помню библиотека C# позволяет использовать неявное количество символов в просмотрах назад, поэтому что бы не захватывать все отдельно в группу можно попробовать сделать так:

```
(?<=^[0-9]+\.)[\s\S]+?(?=^[0-9]+\.|\Z)
```

После цифра одной или более с точкой, захватываем все пробельный и не пробельные символы с ленивым квантификатором (1 и более) до первого совпадения с числом после которого идет точка в начале строки или до конца текста.
Данные будут выглядеть сразу как и требовалось без необходимости получения их из группы.
Но отвечая на вопрос продублирую комментарий:
Попробуйте в группе позитивного просмотра вперед добавить логическое ИЛИ, указав завершение текста `\Z`